# Proof by induction of a regression formula (series)

Tags: induction, regression

As part of the curriculum, we have recently been working on proofs by induction. During the exercises I encountered an exercise that I do not know how to solve, I would be happy to help.
Sorry beforehand that I am attaching a picture, I could not raise the question as a built-in code on the site.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UnBa.png)
To the best of my understanding, there is a need to prove by induction of n, on the one hand, and on the other hand to prove that there is n0 so that the argument will be correct.
I'm pretty lost..

I tried to prove for N + 1 organs, but then I did not understand how to proceed to exclude the existence of the n0 requested .

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could write: 
$a_{n+1}=2a_n + a_{n-1}$. Then you apply the induction hypothesis $a_n \leq 2a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$. This gives $$a_{n+1} \leq 2[(\frac{5}{2})^n +(\frac{5}{2})^{n-1}] = \frac{5^{n} + 2\cdot 5^{n-1}}{2^{n+1}} \leq (\frac{5}{2})^{n+1}$$
Using the $n_0$ Noble Mushtak found, this should complete the proof by induction.

Comment: Thank you very much for the formula, but I still do not understand how the proof of induction is reflected in your solution.
What's more, if I put the value Mushtak found, I'll get it 6675.720.. <=23841.85..
A numerical solution, which I do not understand how it answers the question, when we are asked to prove by induction on n

Comment: Firstly, you have found a value $n_0$ for which the formula holds. Then you say, let's assume that this formula holds for any $n$ and then see if it has to hold also for $n+1$. This is what is proven in the formula above, namely that if $a_n \leq (\frac{5}{2})^n$ then $a_{n+1} \leq (\frac{5}{2})^{n+1}$. Since it hold for $a_{10}$, it must then hold for $a_{11}$. But then it must also hold for $a_{12}$ and then $a_{13}$ and so on. I hope this clears things up a little

Comment: You did succeed.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the value of $n_0$ by guess and check.

$$n=1\implies a_n=6 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=2.5$$
$$n=2\implies a_n=7 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=6.25$$
$$n=3\implies a_n=20 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=15.625$$
$$n=4\implies a_n=47 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=39.0625$$
$$n=5\implies a_n=114 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=97.65625$$
$$n=6\implies a_n=275 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=244.140625$$
$$n=7\implies a_n=664 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=610.3515625$$
$$n=8\implies a_n=1603 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=1525.87890625$$
$$n=9\implies a_n=3870 > \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=3814.697265625$$
$$n=10\implies a_n=9343 \leq \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n=9536.7431640625$$

Thus, your value of $n_0$ is $10$ since that's when $a_n \leq \left(\frac 5 2\right)^n$ first becomes true.

Comment: You are right, and indeed I have reached this value, but where is the part of the proof by induction expressed in this calculation?